# tell npm install to get rid of no longer needed dependencies

Tags: json, node.js, dependencies, npm

I added a couple of libraries to my package.json file, but now I found out I no longer need them

Is there some command line parameter to pass to `npm install` to tell it to remove no longer needed packages? that is, those packages in node_modules that are no longer in package.json

Or shall I just remove the node_modules folder and run `npm install` once again... (I was hoping for a smarter solution)

--

I found out that `npm ls` correctly recognizes no longer needed libraries as *extraneous*

Answer (score 2):

You can do `npm prune` to remove extraneous packages. [Link](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-prune.html) to docs.